# how to bind string[] array to only one column of listview

Tags: asp.net

select | Application No.

---

There are two columns in my listview(generated by following code) where 1st column is select link while other is simple column with header application number (header shown above):

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListBox1" runat ="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
        onselectedindexchanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <LayoutTemplate>
      <table style="border: solid 2px #336699;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all">
         <tr style="background-color: #336699; color: White;">
            <th>Select</th>
            <th>Application No.</th>

         </tr>
         <tbody>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </LayoutTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server" />
         </td>
         <td><%# Container.DataItem %></td>

      </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>
   <SelectedItemTemplate>
      <tr style="background-color: #336699; color: White;">
         <td>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server"
               ForeColor="White" />
         </td>
         <td><%# Container.DataItem %></td>

      </tr>
   </SelectedItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>
```

now i want to display application number from string[] array. How i can do that plz help..?

Answer (score 0):

```
 //are you using datatable as datasource?, if so
        var arr = new[] { "one", "two" };
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ApplicationNo", typeof(string));
        var i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            dr["ApplicationNo"] = arr[i];
            dt.AcceptChanges();
            i++;
        }
```

ListBox1.DataSource=dt;
ListBox1.DataBind();

Comment: i am not using anything like this because i didn't know.. after trying your code it's not showing anything means no listview :( i was previously using ListBox1.DataSource=arr; ListBox1.DataBind(); it was atleast showing listview but when i replaced it with your code it's not showing listview either :'(

Comment: should i replace following code with something

    <td><%# Container.DataItem %></td>
?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<asp:ListView ID="mylist" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="mylist_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table style="border: solid 2px #336699;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" rules="all">
                <tr style="background-color: #336699; color: White;">
                    <th>
                        Select
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Application No.
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton OnClick="lnkSelect_OnClick"  ID="lnkSelect" Text="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' CommandName="Select" runat="server" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Container.DataItem %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color: #336699; color: White;">
                <td>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" runat="server"
                        ForeColor="White" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%# Container.DataItem %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

IList<string> myList = new List<string>();
        myList.Add("1");
        myList.Add("3");
        myList.Add("2");
        myList.Add("4");


mylist.DataSource = myList;
            mylist.DataBind();
```

**OR**

```
string[] myList = new string[] { "1","2","3" };


            mylist.DataSource = myList;
            mylist.DataBind();



protected void lnkSelect_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string val = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton)(sender)).CommandArgument;
    }
```

Comment: its not working already tried.. 'Application number' column appears to be blank.

Comment: In my demo, "ApplicationNo" display with "1,2,3,4..." value. So is it your display format?

Comment: I think the problem is with  <td><%# Container.DataItem %></td> what should i replace with  Container.DataItem so that it takes values from my list.????

Comment: i am not changing your aspx page code i just copy your code and put in my application. is it display perfect. I updated my code which is display perfectly. Let me know if any issue..

Comment: Jeet Bhatt kindly tell how can i get the selected value from list view for example list view showing 1,2,3.. if user selects 2 then how can i get what user has selected and perform operations on that?

Comment: Please check my updated code. I changed LinkButton code and also add one LinkButton Click event for getting value.

Comment: yes, i've used your code but the problem is when i click one row once it's color doesnot change but it's value is shown in label when i click it again its value is not shown but it's color is changed. I don't know whats happening.

Comment: i am didn't get whats your problem? Color changed its default functionality of LinkButton we cant chagned.